# Token in localStorage cleared when dashboard page refresh in Angular Application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to figure out a way to keep my angular variables with page refresh / across components. My workflow is

- user logs in via credentials(Username & Password) and gets an access token
- users access token will be used with every request

Al through my application works fine. When user login and get the access token and save this token in localstorage. And application redirect the user to dashboard component.

But the problem is, If I refresh the page, localstorage becomes blank and application redirect the user to login page again.

I'm pretty new to  angular and cannot figure out a way to retain my data after a page refresh any help would be much appreciated.

**dashboard.component.ts**

[image]

**auth.service.ts**

[image]

**jwt.interceptor.ts**

[image]

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Signin, ResetPassword } from '../model/user.model';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  private URL_Register = 'http://localhost:52718/account/register'; //Register User (Working)
  private URL_Signin = 'http://localhost:52718/account/Signin'; // Login User (Working)
  private URL_Token = 'http://localhost:52718/connect/token'; // Get Token Against Register User (Working)
  private URL_Data = 'http://localhost:52718/api/values'; // Get Token Against Register User (Working)
  private URL_Claims = 'http://localhost:52718/account/Get';
  private URL_PasswordRecovery = 'http://localhost:52718/account/ForgotPassword';
  private URL_ChangePassword = 'http://localhost:52718/account/ChangePassword';
  public isUserAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // {1}

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); // {2}
  }

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private router: Router) { }

  userAuthentication(credientials: Signin) {
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(this.URL_Signin, JSON.stringify(credientials), { headers: reqHeader }).subscribe((data: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token);
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('Auth Service (Method userAuthentication): [HttpError] ' + err.message)
      });
  }


  fetchData() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_Data);
  }

  getUserClaims() {
    return this.http.get(this.URL_Claims);
  }

  logout() {
    // remove user from local storage to log user out
    localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
    this.loggedIn.next(false);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }


  forgotPassword(ResetPassword: ResetPassword) {
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.post(this.URL_PasswordRecovery, JSON.stringify(ResetPassword), { headers: reqHeader }).subscribe((data: any) => { },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('Auth Service (Method userAuthentication): [HttpError] ' + err)
      });;
  }

  changePassword(QueryParams: Object) {
    let reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    return this.http.put(this.URL_ChangePassword, JSON.stringify(QueryParams), { headers: reqHeader }).subscribe((data: any) => {
      localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token);
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('Auth Service (Method changePassword): [HttpError] ' + err)
      });;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not calling logout() or using localStorage.removeItem('userToken') anywhere else?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I fig out my problem is here `return this.loggedIn.asObservable();` when I refresh my dashboard page then by default loggedIn is set to false thats why I'm getting logout everytime when I refresh page. So I update logged in get property into `get isLoggedIn() {
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('userToken');
    if (!currentUser) { }
    this.loggedIn.next(true);
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); // {2}
  }` this and found that right now my problem has been resolved.

Comment: @Powkachu if you have better answer then please post it.

Answer (score 0):

I fig out that if I change my below code

```
get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable(); // {2}
}
```

into

```
get isLoggedIn() { 
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('userToken'); 
    if (!currentUser) { } 
    this.loggedIn.next(true); 
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
}
```

Now I don't need to re-login and local storage also there.

The logic behind the scene was as I set above loggedIn property to false that's why when ever I refresh my page by default loggedIn method redirect me to login page after logout current user. So I modified this property and check if user have token in there browser local storage then don't redirect or don't need to delete its token.

Meantime my problem has been resolved. But Also I'm looking for the better answer.